# How to prove the difference in these conjugate functions approaches 0?

Tags: calculus

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} G'(x)=-\infty$, $G''(x)>0$, $G$ and $G'$ are continuous.

$s=a-G'(x_1)=b-G'(x_2)$, $a<b$.

What to show:
$\lim_{s\rightarrow +\infty}[G(x_1)-G'(x_1)x_1]-[G(x_2)-G'(x_2)x_2]=0$.
My reasoning is: as $s\rightarrow +\infty$, $x_1\rightarrow 0$ and $x_2\rightarrow 0$. If $G(0)$ is well defined, then $G(x_1)\rightarrow G(0)$ and $G(x_2)\rightarrow G(0)$, so $\lim_{s\rightarrow +\infty}G(x_1)-G(x_2)=0$. But I am not sure how to deal with the $G'(x_i)x_i$ part.

I really appreciate your help!

Edit: the motivating example is $G(x)=x\ln x+(1-x) \ln (1-x)$. So $G'(x)=\ln x-\ln (1-x)$, $G''(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{1-x}$. Looks I cannot assume $G''(x)$ is bounded...